# How to add 1 over a complex number?

Tags: complex-numbers

Say you had $z = 3 + i$ and you were asked to find the value of $ z + 1/z$.  Would you just sub z in and find it like an ordinary equation?

I tried this and I ended up with $3 + i$ as my answer but apparently it is $3.3 + 0.9i$.  I can't see how this was found.  I subbed in the $z$ and brought it together in one fraction and them multiplied by the complex conjugate, but it didn't give me the right answer.

Comment: If you have a complex fraction, and you want to get its "a+bi" form,
the trick is to multiply the fraction by its conjugate divided by its conjugate (so it's like multiplying by 1), and then when you open all braces you'll get the numbers in the form of a+bi, while a and b will probably be fractions.

Comment: It's exactly what the other guys here did in their answers, it works almost anytime.

Comment: I think you did the mistake here: $z+\frac1z=\frac{z+1}{z}$. But in the $N^m$, there would be a $z^2$ not $z$. If that is what you did.

Comment: @Taru. Why almost?

Comment: @AdityaAgarwal You're right, it works anytime, "almost" is unrelated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$z=3+i$ 
We have to find $$\frac1z+z$$
So the answer comes out to be $$\frac{(3-i)}{(3+i)(3-i)}+3+i=\frac{3-i}{10}+3+i=3.3+i(0.9)$$
What we did was to just multiply the $N^m$ and $D^m$ by the conjugate of the complex number.

Answer (score 0):

$\displaystyle \frac 1z = \frac {1}{3+i} = \frac{3-i}{(3+i)(3-i)} = \frac{3-i}{3^2 + 1^2} = \frac{3-i}{10} = 0.3 - 0.1i$.

Add that to $z$ to get $3.3 + 0.9i$.